# QGIS Plugin Running in QGIS 3.10 but not in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-3

[image]I am new to QGIS, need your help in fixing one problem. I created a Plugin for QGIS. While creating it, I worked on QGIS 3.10 LTR version for which my plugin is working perfectly.

Now when I shared this Plugin folder with my friend who is using QGIS 3.4 LTR version, the Plugin execution is giving error with the message like `there was errors executing the algorithm`.

I am unable to figure out about exact problem.

Comment: Welcome to gis StackExchange. What is the exact error message? LTR is now 3.10. Why not have your friend upgrade?

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto, Thank you for the reply. I added the image for the error message in the post. As it is multi line message.

Comment: It would be really better to post the error message as text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this problem. Some processing tools worked in QGIS 3.8, but doesn't work in QGIS 3.4.

I don't know the reason, but changing `native` word into `qgis` in all `processing.run ("native:tool_name", ...)` solved the problem. (`native:intersection -> qgis:intersection`)

Comment: Thank you Kadir. This solution worked.